# back button isn't doing anything using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, mean-stack

This is how I specify my route.

```
.state('app.partners', {
        url:'/partners',
        templateUrl: 'partials/dashboard/partners.html'
      })
      .state('app.partners.id', {
        url:'/:id',
        templateUrl: 'partials/dashboard/partners.html'
      })
```

Then I do this in my controller

```
$state.go('app.partner.id',{id:partnerId});
    $http.get('/app/endpoint?id='+$state.params.id || null).then(function(response){
//do something
});
```

I manage to see the browser url changed but when I click back, nothing happens?

Answer (score 0):

You probably have an error in your console that's causing the back button to break.

Also, you call `$state.go()` with `app.partner.id` (singular) but you defined your route as `app.partners.id` (plural)

Comment: no error in the console. and fixed the typo the thing still not working.